# How to start work on Solrnet

Tags: solr, solrnet

I have installed Apache Tomcat 6 and configure Solr 1.4. Now Solr service running successfully.
In Solr 1.4 has two important file solrconfig.xml and schema.xml to configure c# application with Solr service.
But whenver I changed schema.xml file according to sql table’s field it’s stop the Solr service.

so tell me step by step to configure solrconfig.xml and schema.xml

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the question isn't clear or is too broad, so I can only give general advice and point to documentation.

> But whenver I changed schema.xml file according to sql table’s field it’s stop the Solr service.

Yes, after changing your schema you either have to restart your Solr instance, or, if you are using [Cores](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) (recommended), you have to [reload the changed core](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#RELOAD).

> tell me step by step to configure solrconfig.xml and schema.xml

Just change the files according to your needs. The Solr package contains numerous examples, all thoroughly commented. [Documentation on solrconfig.xml is here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml). [Documentation on schema.xml is here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml). After making any change in solrconfig.xml you have to restart your Solr instance.

Also, when making changes to the schema, make sure you reflect those changes in your [SolrNet mapping](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Mapping).